# How to access list<ParseObject> from other class?

Tags: java, android

Android and java beginner has now 2 days trying to figure this one out.

I have

```
public class searchFromServer {
    public List<String> lightHouses = new ArrayList<String>();
    LightHouseList mLightHouseList = new LightHouseList();




     List  searchLightHouses(String find) {

         ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("userLocation");
         query.whereEqualTo("username",find);
         query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
             public void done(List<ParseObject> searchedLightHouseList, ParseException e) {
                 if (e == null) {

                     for (int i = 0; i < searchedLightHouseList.size(); i++) {
                         mLightHouseList.addObjectToLightHousesList(searchedLightHouseList.get(i));

                         Log.d("parse", "searchedLightHouseList item #" + i + searchedLightHouseList.get(i).get("location"));
                     }
                     Log.d("parse", "Retrieved " + searchedLightHouseList.size() + " scores");
                 } else {
                     Log.d("parse", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                 }
             }
         });
         Log.d("test", String.valueOf(mLightHouseList.getLightHousesListSize()));
         return lightHouses;
    }

}
```

If i have understood right, public void done method is creating list of ParseObjects and that list is named "searchedLightHouseList"?

How i can access this List from other classes?

May recent try was to make Class and use that as a "storage", but nothing goes in there. at least

```
Log.d("test", String.valueOf(mLightHouseList.getLightHousesListSize()));
```

shows 0.

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.parse.ParseObject;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

/**
 * Created by U36J on 11.9.2015.
 */
public class LightHouseList {
    private List<ParseObject> LightHousesList = new List<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void add(int location, ParseObject object) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean add(ParseObject object) {
            return false;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean addAll(int location, Collection<? extends ParseObject> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends ParseObject> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void clear() {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean contains(Object object) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ParseObject get(int location) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int indexOf(Object object) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEmpty() {
            return false;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Iterator<ParseObject> iterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int lastIndexOf(Object object) {
            return 0;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator() {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ListIterator<ParseObject> listIterator(int location) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public ParseObject remove(int location) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean remove(Object object) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> collection) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public ParseObject set(int location, ParseObject object) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return 0;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public List<ParseObject> subList(int start, int end) {
            return null;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Object[] toArray() {
            return new Object[0];
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public <T> T[] toArray(T[] array) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    public void addObjectToLightHousesList (ParseObject obj){
        LightHousesList.add(obj);
    }

    public  ParseObject getLightHousesListObject (int i){
        return LightHousesList.get(i);
    }

    public int getLightHousesListSize () {return LightHousesList.size();
    }
}
```